How to Sum by field on different table
I'm trying to create a measure that will Sum the forecasted and actual proceeds a client receives for all of the companies they own.  Data model is structured in a star schema with Clients as the fact table and all other tables as dimensional.
Data Model:
DimSubCompanies

ClientID
SubCompanyName

FactClients

ID

DimPaymentActual

PaymentID
ClientID
Net to Client

DimPaymentForecasted

PaymentID
ClientID
Net to Client

The table I'm trying to make should look like this



SubCompanyName
Forecasted Net to Client
Actual Net to Client




SubCompany1
100
0


SubCompany2
500



SubCompany3
250
250



Instead the current table I have looks like this where it's summing the entire client across all the companies they own.



SubCompanyName
Forecasted Net to Client
Actual Net to Client




SubCompany1
850
250


SubCompany2
850
250


SubCompany3
850
250



How can I get my table to look like the first one?
Link to sample file

Can you share a sample .pbix?

@davidebacci I added a link to a sample file with scrubbed data.

@MyNameHere why are columns such as Net to Client is in the dimensions and not the fact table?

After investigating the Data Model provided, I have discovered that the SubCompanies do not have their own unique identifier specific to the company. Which prevents summing the Net to Client by each subcompany. The only identifier is the client name which explains why it's summing the entire client across all the companies they own.
I recommend adding a SubCompanyId column to the DimSubCompanies table. Then replacing the ClientID column with the SubCompanyId column on the DimPaymentActual and DimPaymentForecastedtables. Once the relationships are rebuilt using this schema, the values can be correctly calculated.
